# Errors after updating Flutter to the latest version

Tags: flutter

I updated Flutter to the latest version and since updating I have been getting these errors:

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/persistent-tab-view.widget.dart:368:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

                     ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/animations/animations.dart:55:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-6-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:44:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

                   ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-8-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:44:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

                   ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-11-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

                   ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-12-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-13-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-14-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/getwidget-2.0.5/lib/components/sticky_header/gf_sticky_header_builder.dart:63:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').

            WidgetsBinding.instance?.endOfFrame.then((_) {
                           ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:167:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
        SchedulerBinding.instance?.cancelFrameCallbackWithId(_frameCallbackID);
                         ^

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:170:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
          SchedulerBinding.instance?.scheduleFrameCallback(_beginFrame) ?? -1;
                           ^

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:272:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

        SchedulerBinding.instance?.cancelFrameCallbackWithId(_frameCallbackID);
                         ^
```

`flutter doctor:`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.13.0-0.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1645], locale tr-TR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.13)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

I upgraded Flutter with flutter upgrade. I started getting these errors after upgrading. I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. What is the problem? How can I solve it? I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Just remove null-checks (! And ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check "null-safety" checks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't updated the dependencies of your project.

1. Take look at your pubspec.yaml and update all third-party dependencies. Also try to run "flutter pub outdated" from the root of your project.
2. Update your dart language version to the latest version supported by flutter in pubspec.yaml:

```
  environment:
    sdk:">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: I've updated the 6 packages to the latest version, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you try flutter clean command after updating your packages ?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

those warnings are mainly from third-party plugins and they can be fixed by running
`dart fix --apply`, It seemss to be introduced with this intended change #89451.

However, these are just warnings it shouldn't affect the build process.
Closing as this is not really a bug.